# What URIs are accessed by drush?

Tags: drush

What URIs are accessed by drush up? Is it drupal.org? Are there any other URIs?
I have tried using drush up --debug, but I can't seem to find a list of URIs. I have also googled it using the key words drush access URL and drush access URI, among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took a look through the drush code.  In Drush/UpdateService/ReleaseInfo.php, you can see that drush grabs project release info via this url:
https://updates.drupal.org/release-history

You can test it yourself - try https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x for example.

The release info contains the download links for the projects.

Drush actually has two package handlers, git and wget (see commands/pm/download.pm.inc)

The wget one uses the download_link from the release history, and the git method uses git.drupal.org.  See commands/pm/package_handler/wget.inc and commands/pm/package_handler/git_drupalorg.inc

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to `drush dl`, then by default Drush downloads from drupal.org, if you don't tell Drush to use another URL.
For example, if you use `drush dl views --source="updates.modules.org/history"`, Drush would probably download the Views module from modules.org, instead of drupal.org. From where the module would be downloaded depends from what updates.modules.org/history/views/7.x (for Drupal 7) or updates.modules.org/history/views/8.x (for Drupal 8) returns.

If you look at what https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x retuns, you will notice a line like `<download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.14.tar.gz</download_link>`, which is telling to Drush to download the Views module version 7.x-3.14 from https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/views-7.x-3.14.tar.gz.